# Oracle DB table not updating after running merge query in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, oracle, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to create the following Class in Python

1. Establishes a connection to Oracle using SQLAlchemy
2. Uploads every .csv file from a given directory to Oracle
3. Adds a blank email column to each file
4. Matches emails from the master database in oracle to each file by matching on md5 hashed emails

What I have so far almost works but it doesn't update the emails in the 2nd file. When I run the debugger in Pycharm, I get the correct updated amount of rows but it seems like it's not committing to the table. From what I've seen online, I don't have an option to commit anything. I've also extracted the query that get's passed to python and it ran correctly in Oracle. I'm not sure if this is an Oracle issue or if I'm doing something wrong in Python. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Here's the code

```
class OracleETL:

    def __init__(self):
        self.engine = create_engine(config.ORACLE)


    def __enter__(self):
        self.conn = self.engine.connect()
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        self.conn.close()


    def upload_to_oracle(self, direct):
        for f in os.listdir(direct):
            df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(direct,f), sep=',', index_col=None, dtype=str)
            db_types = {c: types.VARCHAR(255)
                            for c in df.columns[df.dtypes == 'object'].tolist()}

            df.to_sql(name=os.path.splitext(f)[0],con=self.conn, if_exists='replace',
                          dtype=db_types, index=False)

    def add_email_column(self, tablename, email_col='EMAIL'):
          query = q.add_email_column % (tablename, email_col)
          self.conn.execute(query)

    def match_emails_to_file(self, tablename, email_col='EMD5'):
          query = q.merge_emails % (tablename.upper(), email_col)
          self.conn.execute(query)
```

And here's the merge query:

```
MERGE  /*+ PARALLEL(T1,32) PARALLEL(T2,32) USE_HASH(T1,T2)*/
INTO    "%s" T1   
USING   (
       SELECT * FROM  "MASTER"
       ) T2
ON      (lower(T1.%s) = lower(T2.EMD5))
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE
SET     T1."EMAIL"=T2."EMAIL
```

Comment: Should probably edit the answer to mention that connections also work in autocommit mode, if no explicit transaction is ongoing.